How can I completely solve all issues related to antimeridian?
Assume I want to work with raster and vector data for regions near antimeridian (180 degrees).
Known problems are:

Incorrect visualisation of polygons (and probably features of different types) intersecting antimeridian
Possible topological errors in that areas

The first problem is uncomfortable, but I can stand it, it's only visualisation. The second is critical, as I want to prepare the project in GRASS GIS and then process it in the following way:

I choose an extent of interest
I clip all layers from the project
I save these parts as new files for further work

All processing is done with GRASS command line scripts, so I don't want to get any topological or other errors.
First, I thought that if I work in appropriate projection, not in EPSG:4326, I should manage it. So, I saved my vector layers in appropriate projection (EPSG:3832) and prepared them for work.
I created a new GRASS location in EPSG:3832. Loaded my vectors. Then I tried to load my raster (project PROBA-V data (https://zenodo.org/records/3939050/files/PROBAV_LC100_global_v3.0.1_2019-nrt_Discrete-Classification-map_EPSG-4326.tif?download=1).
When I tried it from GRASS GUI with r.import I got warnings:
invalid east longitude 330
WARNING: Unable to determine area of interest for '+proj=merc +lon_0=150 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +no_defs +a=6378137 +rf=298.257223563 +towgs84=0.000,0.000,0.000 +type=crs '

And then errors:
ERROR: Unable to initialize coordinate transformation
ERROR: Unable to reproject to source location

So, it's impossible to load the source raster from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3832.
What would be a correct way to get any clip from this raster of a rather big region that includes 180 meridian in EPSG:3832?
If it's impossible, pity. But I still can work back in EPSG:4326.
So I tried to cut all polygons (in QGIS) with a rectangle with 180 degrees right edge. So, I got polygons intersecting antimeridian divided into two features. I saved this new layer in EPSG:4326. Then I imported it into GRASS and got an image represented here. Is it normal? If it's the question of representation only and I won't get any topological errors - it's ok so.

If it's normal it could be a partial solution, because I will be able to import my raster as it is.
Although the question about raster stays.

Depending on the extent of your region of interest (just Pacific area?), you could use a projection that is centered on Pacific to avoid the problems with antimeridian

Yes, I do it. I use EPSG:3832. But it's only a problem of representation. More critical for me is avoiding topological errors

You won't have topological errors when both layer and project CRS are in EPSG:3832 and your feathers are not expanding around the whole globe. If that would be the case, you could simply split up your vector features, based on the intersection with a grid. See here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/487504/88814

Your raster is huge, by the way: X: 362880 Y: 141120 pixels.... Maybe that's also a problem

Don't "load the source raster from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3832". Rather, first Warp (reproject) your raster to EPSG:3832 before you start processing. Make sure every layer you use is in the same CRS.
If you still encounter problems, you best create a grid that divides your extent in like 10 * 10 cells or so, then make the intersection of your layers with the grid cell to split you features and rasters to the size of these cells. Like this, it should work.
